# R: Efficient way of assigning values to data.table with multiple conditions

Tags: r, data.table

I have a ~10 mm lines data.table in R and I'm writing code to update some of the values of a variable. Unfortunately, it has to be done with a loop statement, so when I use the assignment operator `:=` with multiple conditions for `i`, the code gets extremely slow (~2.3 min per loop). I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of combining the multiple conditions and the assignment operator. For example:

```
    require(data.table)
    set.seed(123)
    x <- data.table(V1 = LETTERS[1:3], V2 = rnorm(10), V3 = NA)
    y <- data.table(V1 = LETTERS[1],V3 = TRUE)

    x
       V1          V2 V3
    1:  A -0.56047565 NA
    2:  B -0.23017749 NA
    3:  C  1.55870831 NA
    4:  A  0.07050839 NA
    5:  B  0.12928774 NA
    6:  C  1.71506499 NA
    7:  A  0.46091621 NA
    8:  B -1.26506123 NA
    9:  C -0.68685285 NA
   10:  A -0.44566197 NA

    y
       V1   V3
    1:  A TRUE
```

What I need to do is to assign `y$V3` to `x$V3` given certain conditions. The result could be achieved by using:

```
    x[V1==y$V1 & V2 >= 0,V3:=y$V3]

    x
       V1          V2   V3
    1:  A -0.56047565   NA
    2:  B -0.23017749   NA
    3:  C  1.55870831   NA
    4:  A  0.07050839 TRUE
    5:  B  0.12928774   NA
    6:  C  1.71506499   NA
    7:  A  0.46091621 TRUE
    8:  B -1.26506123   NA
    9:  C -0.68685285   NA
   10:  A -0.44566197   NA
```

However, this is excessively time-consuming in my code.

Thanks,

Comment: You'd probably be better off setting the key to be `V1` on both sets and then doing an `x[y]` join.

Comment: I think this is going to be hard to solve without knowing more. I just ran your operation on 10M rows and it completed in 1 second... I feel that there must be more going on here

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for the response. In this case, is there a way to include the second condition `V2 >= 0` in the join statement? In my actual code, I don't have a primary key. It is instead a combination of ~10 condition statement that is "making up" for the absence of a PK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In latest development version 1.9.7 you can find non-equi joins. Then you can just add `V2 := 0` to your `y` dataset and proceed with non-equi join.

```
y[, V2 := 0]
x[y, V3 := i.V3, on=.(V1, V2>=V2)][]
#    V1          V2   V3
# 1:  A -0.56047565   NA
# 2:  B -0.23017749   NA
# 3:  C  1.55870831   NA
# 4:  A  0.07050839 TRUE
# 5:  B  0.12928774   NA
# 6:  C  1.71506499   NA
# 7:  A  0.46091621 TRUE
# 8:  B -1.26506123   NA
# 9:  C -0.68685285   NA
#10:  A -0.44566197   NA
```

Be aware that join on `double` (numeric) field might be affected by floating point, read `?setNumericRounding` for details.

To install latest development version use the following:

```
install.packages("data.table", repos="https://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It seems to fit my need, but I'm having some trouble with the syntax. I checked the documentation for the `data.table` package, but I could not understand how the `on=` argument differentiates between objects in `x` and `y` in the conditional statements. For example, how does the function identify which `V2` is which in the `V2>=V2` statement?

In addition, is it possible that some conditions refer to only one data.table (e.g. `V2 >= 0.5` instead of `V2 >= V2`)?

Comment: @PietroFranzero good question, if you look into [data.table#1452](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1452) you will see that `?data.table` (documentation) is not yet completed task. In `on`, the LHS refers to `x` while RHS to `i`, as it's sequence when you type them. Single column name is expanded to `==`, so here: `on=.(V1==V1, V2>=V2)`.

Comment: @PietroFranzero the second question about using expressions (not just refer column names) in `on` is still on todo list, for details see [data.table#1639](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639).